# Why I cannot use `\\` (making new line) at the same time with "resizebox"?

Tags: latex

I have a over wide multi-line equation But I don't want make one more line, since the equation is only a tiny bit wider than the text-line. Then I consider use the command `\rescalebox` as follows.

```
\begin{align}
\resizebox{.9\hsize}{!}
 {S & = A + B + C \nonumber  \\
    & + D +E +F.}
\end{align}
```

However, it only works if I remove the break line symbol `\\`, otherwise I get error about missing `\endgroup`. After reading some other problems with about resizing or rescaling, I still cannot figure out why I cannot use `\\` and `\resizebox` at the same time. Can any one help me with this, or is there other way to fit/rescale a multi-line equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first, you can try if something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

{\small %
\begin{align}
S & = A + B + C \nonumber \\
  & + D +E +F.
\end{align}
}%

\end{document}
```

can help you ([reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33585/change-font-size-of-an-align-environment/33589#33589)). Even better:

```latex
{\fontsize{9}{8}\selectfont %
\begin{align}
S & = A + B + C \nonumber  \\
  & + D +E +F.
\end{align}
}%
```

Here `9` and `8` are the font size and the lineskip in pt, obviously you can change them as you like (9pt is 9/10 of the default 10pt, as in your `.9\hsize`). Consider that the lineskip should be a little smaller than the font size.